# "Lernt zu zuhören" oder "Lernt zuzuhören"?

Tags: imperative, separable

> Lernt zu zuhören
>   Lernt zuzuhören

Which version would correctly communicate the message "learn to listen!" given that zuhören is a separable verb? Or are they both false?

Comment: Only the latter (_zuzuhören_) is correct. Sorry I can't give you a more well-founded answer.

Comment: Note that *lernt zuhören* is also possible.

Answer (score 8):

This is correct:

> Lernt zuzuhören.

This is wrong:

> Lernt zu zuhören.

The verb *zuhören* is a separable verb (correct: *»Ich höre dir zu.«* Wrong: *»<del>Ich zuhöre dir.</del>«*). And this means, that "zu" can not be used as a separate word, but must be squeezed between the prefix and the stem.

---

Another example (yes, it's constructed, but still valid):
The German verb *"zupfen"* means *"to pluck"* or *"to pick"*. But you also could imagine to pluck on a tiny curtain of a doll house to close it. For that you could use the verb *"zuzupfen"* which maybe could be translated as *"to pluck to close something"* or maybe even *"to close-pluck"* (I know, that this is bad English, but in German this is possible):

Usage as normal infinitive (together with a modal verb):

> Ich möchte den Vorhang **zuzupfen.**
>   I want to close-pluck the curtain.

But this verb is a separable verb:

> Ich **zupfe** den Vorhang **zu.**
>   I close-pluck the curtain.
>   (word-by-word translation with German grammar: *"I pluck the curtain close."*)

And now you can use this separable verb in the construction "zu + Infinitiv":

> Ich versuche den Vorhang **zuzuzupfen.**
>   I try to close-pluck the curtain.

The 1st *"zu"* in *"zuzuzupfen"* is the prefix of the separable verb that means *"to close".* The second *"zu"* is from the construction *"zu + Infinitiv"* and appears as *"to"* in the english translation, and the 3rd *"zu"* is part of the stem *"zupfen"* (*"to pluck"*).

(Word-by-word translation with English words but German grammar: *"I try the curtain close-to-pluck"*)

Comment: Für *„lernen, die Tür zuzuschließen“* wäre die Schriftform wohl lesbarer ausgefallen ;)

Comment: +1 for *zuzuzupfen*